# Unable to get firebase token on DP6.1

Tags: android-things

I have my RPi 3 connected to the internet through an ethernet connection. But I keep receiving these messages on the LogCat.

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11910000 but found 11745330
W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
W/FirebaseInstanceId: No response
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: TIMEOUT
W/FirebaseInstanceId: No response
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: TIMEOUT
W/FirebaseInstanceId: No response
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: TIMEOUT
```

However, firebase cloud messaging works perfectly fine on DP6. Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

The [release notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html) page for Android Things indicates the version of Play Services available for each release of the OS. Developer Preview 6 (and 6.1) includes Play Services version 11.6.0, however it looks like you might be trying to use the latest (11.8.0) client library in your app. The client library version(s) in your `build.gradle` file must be equal to or lower than the version on the system you are using.

Comment: definitely the right answer, just downgrade to 11.6.0 does the trick!